# PHP $_POST index name from array Undefined index: Pruningbox1

Tags: php

Im very new to programming and im a bit confused as to why this is happening.

I have form that is generated differently for different users based on a mysql database table.

on this form you hit submit and an array of the inputs that have been created in the form is passed to the submit form.

within my submit form i have the following code

```
foreach ($PostArray1 as $boxname1) 
{
echo $boxname1;
echo $_POST[$boxname1];  //------------Line 92
echo '<br/>';
}

echo $_POST['Hand_Weedingbox1'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['Weed_Burningbox1'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['Herbicide_Applicationbox1'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['Remove_Litterbox1'];
```

Output of $_POST array

```
Array
(
[notes] => 
[Hand_Weedingbox1] => 0:01
[Weed_Burningbox1] => 0:02
[Herbicide_Applicationbox1] => 0:03
[Remove_Litterbox1] => 0:04
[PostArray1] => Hand_Weedingbox1, Weed_Burningbox1, 
Herbicide_Applicationbox1, Remove_Litterbox1
)
```

Output of $PostArray1

Array ( [0] => Hand_Weedingbox1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Fmg.png) => Weed_Burningbox1 [2] => 
   Herbicide_Applicationbox1 [3] => Remove_Litterbox1 )

here is the output i get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Fmg.png)

Comment: Show us the code where you build the `$PostArray1` array. Or, better, the whole page code.

Comment: would a print_r of the array be ok??? as the code is hugeeee???

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Hand_Weedingbox1
    [1] =>  Weed_Burningbox1
    [2] =>  Herbicide_Applicationbox1
    [3] =>  Remove_Litterbox1

)

Comment: Make a `print_r` of `$_POST` then. But like this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, TRUE) . '</pre>';`. Show it in the question, e.g. reedit your question and put it in there.

Comment: Array
(
    [notes] => 
    [Hand_Weedingbox1] => 0:01
    [Weed_Burningbox1] => 0:02
    [Herbicide_Applicationbox1] => 0:03
    [Remove_Litterbox1] => 0:04
    [PostArray1] => Hand_Weedingbox1, Weed_Burningbox1, Herbicide_Applicationbox1, Remove_Litterbox1
)

Comment: as you can see PostArray1 is passed to the submit code as comma seperated values.. It is turned into an array by the submit page. output of that array is further up the comments

Comment: Which is line 92?

Comment: Updated OP to show line 92

Comment: If you remove line 92 what do you see as result?

Comment: echos out the input names:                         
Hand_Weedingbox1 
Weed_Burningbox1 
Herbicide_Applicationbox1 
Remove_Litterbox1

Comment: Hm, that's strange, because it seem no problem with the code and $_POST array. Write `var_dump($boxname1);` after `echo $boxname1;`.

Comment: i think that solves the problem i will have a play

Comment: Hand_Weedingbox1
C:\wamp64\www\council\submitinspection.php:92:string 'Hand_Weedingbox1' (length=16)

Weed_Burningbox1
C:\wamp64\www\council\submitinspection.php:92:string ' Weed_Burningbox1' (length=17)

Herbicide_Applicationbox1
C:\wamp64\www\council\submitinspection.php:92:string ' Herbicide_Applicationbox1' (length=26)

Remove_Litterbox1
C:\wamp64\www\council\submitinspection.php:92:string ' Remove_Litterbox1' (length=18)

Comment: there is a space before the start of each index name except the first

Comment: Ah, that's it indeed! It tries to fetch `$_POST['  Weed_Burningbox1']`  - for example - on line 92. But only 'Weed_Burningbox1' exists in `$_POST`. Congratulations! ;-)

Comment: There are the spaces after each comma in `PostArray1` value of `$_POST`. Good luck further.

Comment: $PostArray1 = str_replace(' ', '', $PostArray1);                                      Solved the problem without the var_dump i never would have found it... you have taught me a valuable troubleshooting tool

Comment: Better directly post the values list without spaces after commas.

Comment: how do i give you a +1

Comment: Yes, `var_dump` rocks! :-) And the `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, TRUE) . '</pre>';` too! Remember them.

Comment: No need. It was you, that found the problem. And you have +5 from me for your effort to reedit and answer to all our questions ;-)

Comment: thankyou so much hopefully i learn quickly this is all still very new to me

Comment: You are welcome. You must not learn quick, but thoroughly. In time you'll gain more and more experience. Always read the docus for the functions and principles that you are using and you'll learn a lot from there. php.net is a great place for it.